# flutter custom widget is not showing children

Tags: flutter, widget

I am following an outdated tutorial for building a custom widget but so far I can't make it visible inside the custom widget: nothing placed inside RusableCard's children is visible in the app. What can I do?

```
....

                  child: ReusableCard(
                    color: activeCardColor,
                    cardChild: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.search, size: 80),                       
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Text(
                          'MALE',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            color: Color(0xFF8D8E96),
                      
                ...

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({
    required this.color,
    this.cardChild,
  });

  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Container` child on `ReusableCard`. Call child on Container. make sure to handle null value.

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({
    required this.color,
    this.cardChild,
  });

  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
     child:cardChild!=null? cardChild: null,// handle here 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Container can have null value .